# Solve inequality where $n$ occurs in both basis and exponent

Tags: inequality

I want to solve the following inequality for $n$:

$\binom nk\left(1-2^{-k}\right)^{n-k} < 1$

Precisely for a given $k$ I want to show that the inequality holds if $n$ is sufficiently large. Is there a generic method for such a task?

/edit: Actually just after sending this question I got an idea: Is it sufficient to say that $\left(1-2^{-k}\right)^{n-k}$ is exponential in $n$ while $\binom nk$ is only polynomial? So the former tends faster to $0$ than the latter tends to $\infty$?

Comment: Is it not? But $\binom nk = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \leq \frac{n^k}{k!}$ that looks polynomial in $n$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: For fixed $k, {n \choose k}$ is a $k^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial in $n$  For example, if $k=3, {n \choose k}=\frac 16n(n-1)(n-2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be true for large enough $n$, just as you say. If you want to find the value of $n$, you can use Stirling's approximation on the factorials.  You want $$\log {n \choose k} +(n-k) \log (1-2^{-k}) \lt 0\\(n+\frac 12) \log n -n -(k+\frac 12) \log k +k -(n-k+\frac 12)\log(n-k)+(n-k)-\frac 12\log (2 \pi) +(n-k)\log(1-2^{-k})\lt 0$$  A little iteration will find $n$ as the logs vary slowly.